# How to solve pylint (too-many-return-statements) elegantly?

Tags: python, pylint

[image]
The example of too-many-return-statements is as above, but my scenario is as follows, how to make the function more beautiful？

```
def func():
    # do something1
    ret1 = do_something1()
    if ret1 != 0:
        return ret1

    # do something2
    ret2 = do_something2()
    if ret2 != 0:
        return ret2
    # ......
    return 0
```

Comment: use `if... elif ... els`, and instead of `return`ing, assign to a fariable, i.e. `result = ret1` then simply do `return `result` after the `if ... elif ... else`

Comment: You could solve it by disabling this linter rule. Many programmers would consider your current code fine.

Comment: Also [please do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12299000); post the code instead.

Comment: I agree with @kaya3 . Your current code is just fine, especially since you have to do something in between the return tests.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
def foo(x):
    nums = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven']
    return 'This is ' + nums[x-1]
```

to solve your example. And you could solve your scenario like this:

```
def func():
    functions = [do_something1,do_something2,...]
    for function in functions:
        ret = function()
        if ret != 0:
            return ret
    return 0
```

Comment: ret* is the return value obtained after calling the function. If the previous return is not 0, there is no need to continue execution

Comment: You can loop on ``functions = [do_something1,do_something2,...]`` and lazily call it inside the loop

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this example](https://vald-phoenix.github.io/pylint-errors/plerr/errors/design/R0911.html).

It converted:

```py
def func(x):
    if x == 1:
        return "hi1"
    if x == 2:
        return "hi2"
    if x == 3:
        return "hi3"
    if x == 4:
        return "hi4"
    if x == 5:
        return "hi5"
    if x == 6:
        return "hi6"
    if x == 7:
        return "hi7"
```

to:

```py
d = {1: "hi1", 2: "hi2", 3: "hi3", 4: "hi4", 5: "hi5", 6: "hi6", 7: "hi7"}
def func(x):
    return d[x]
```

Just to silence it another option is:

```py
def func(x):
    if x == something1:
        res = "something1"
    elif x == something2:
        res = "something2"
    elif x == something3:
        res = "something3"
    elif x == something4:
        res = "something4"
    elif x == something5:
        res = "something5"
    elif x == something6:
        res = "something6"
    elif x == something7:
        res = "something7"
    else:
        res = "default"
    return res
```

You can also silence it in `settings.json` file if you think it's too strict rule which I think it is:

```json
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=R0911"
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func():
  res = default_res

  if foo:
    res = res_foo
    
  elif bar:
    res = res_bar
    
  return res
```

I recommend doing it this way

Comment: This adds another variable assignment and is thus slower and even harder to read in this case, i'd never ever do this just to prevent a linter message

Comment: I disagree. It is much more readable if you are using meaningful variable names. How can you care about the speed of variable assignment while using python.

Comment: Why would you bother though? It takes longer to execute, longer to write, harder to maintain, and is arguably less readable because you need to make sure nothing happens with that variable again and there is not a lot of brackets or similar infront. There is 0 reason to dothis in this case

Answer (score 0):

Using some form of lookup is the way to handle this. A dictionary is a good general purpose idea. A list is useful when the lookup 'key' is an integer.

**HOWEVER**

When using a lookup technique you have to consider that your 'key' may not be available. If your dictionary (for example) has 7 integer keys (1->7 inclusive) and your function is passed a value of 8, what are you going to do? You could allow the exception and deal with that separately or you need to avoid an exception and return some default value, perhaps implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use the proposed solution by pylint documentation:
https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/refactor/too-many-return-statements.html

But IMHO in some case it's impossible to use.

I don't kwonw your specific case, but you can disable pylint in a specific line of code using a comment like this.

```py
def func():  #pylint: disable=R0911
    # do something1
    ret1 = do_something1()
    if ret1 != 0:
        return ret1

    # do something2
    ret2 = do_something2()
    if ret2 != 0:
        return ret2
    # ......
    return 0
```